# How to make Yesod listen on a specific IP?

Tags: yesod

I wrote a Yesod web application called `myapp`, and compiled it (using `stack build`) to `myapp-exe`. Now I want to deploy it, but I do not want to use Keter/scaffolding. The `warp` procedure allows me to specify a port to listen on, but not the IP. Is there any way to make the compiled executable `myapp-exe` to listen only on 127.0.0.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warp provides a function called setHost:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.18/warp-3.2.2/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#v:setHost

You haven't shown how you're running your app, but I'm guessing you need to switch from run to runSettings.

Comment: I apologize, I should have researched more before asking. What a beautiful toy this Yesod is!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I should have researched some more before answering. The answer is to use `runSettings` from `Network.Wai.Handler.Warp` instead of simple `warp`:

```
let stts = setPort 12345 $ setHost "127.0.0.1" defaultSettings
runStderrLoggingT $ withSqlitePool dbfile 10 $ \pool -> liftIO $ do
  waiApp <- toWaiApp $ MyApp pool
  runSettings stts waiApp
```

This allows more settings, while `warp` was just a convenience wrapper.